# Can't figure out $O(n \log n)$ divide-and-conquer algorithm

Tags: algorithms

Let's say you are a manager at a local solar farm. You have a weather forecast for the next $n$ days, and want to know what the most profitable single stretch to run your panels for would be. On some days, the running cost is more than the gain, but it may be worth leaving them on to get the days on either side (your solar panels will only turn on for one single stretch of days). If we are given an array $A[1\ldots n]$ of integers, where $A[k]$ represents the amount of money you would make running your panels on day $k$, find values i and j with $1 ≤ i ≤ j ≤ n$ maximizing $\sum^j _{k=i} A[k]$

Here's an example of what I mean: If $A = [4, −5, 22, −7, 8, −10, 5]$, the solution is $i = 3$ and $j = 5$ (as $22 − 7 + 8 = 23$).

I'm having trouble figuring out an $O(n\log n)$ divide-and-conquer algorithm for this.

Comment: This is the famous maximum sum subarray problem...

Comment: I changed $O(n$ $log$ $n)$ to $O(n\log n)$, coded as O(n\log n).  That is standard usage.  Proper spacing automatically results, as does non-italiciziation of $\log$.  Your way of providing spacing was weird. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: I also changed"$\text{...}$" to "$\ldots$". Also standard. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A divide an conquer algorithm works as follows (it is $O(n)$ though):

For an array $A[1,\dots,n]$, we compute the following three things instead (kind of like having a stronger induction hypothesis):

> 1) A $p$ such that $A[1] + A[2] + \dots + A[p]$ is maximum.
>
> 2) An $s$ such that $A[s] + A[s+1] + \dots + A[n]$ is maximum.
>
> 3) $i \le j$, such that $A[i] + A[i+1] + \dots + A[j]$ is maximum.

Now do a divide and conquer.

Compute these three for $A[1, \dots n/2]$ and $A[n/2+1, \dots, n]$ and combine them, to get the corresponding values for $A[1, \dots, n]$.

Comment: You could implement so it is $\Omega(n \log n)$ instead of $O(n)$ though...

Comment: For the $O(n\log n)$ approach: [geeksforgeeks link](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/divide-and-conquer-maximum-sum-subarray/)